# Vectors on the same plane

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis, plane-geometry

I bumbed into this question and I have been trying to solve it but I got stuck.

> Determine $β$ and $α$ by using vectors such that $A$, $B$ and $C$ lie in the same plane,
>   given that
>   vector $\overrightarrow{AB} = -4\vec\imath - \vec\jmath - 2\vec k$ and
>   vector $\overrightarrow{BC} = 4\vec\imath + (β + 3)\vec\jmath + (α - 6)\vec k$.

I know that to prove they are on the same plane:
$$\vec a \cdot (\vec b \times \vec c) = 0$$

But how to break the vectors $\overrightarrow{AB}$ and $\overrightarrow{BC}$ into component vectors $\vec a$, $\vec b$ and $\vec c$ is what I don't even have a clue of. Please I need help. I'm just so dumb right now.

Comment: If A, B and C are points in 3D space then they are always on the same plane.

Comment: Can I say vector AB is vector a, vector BC is vector b and vector AC is vector c. Is it correct?

Comment: Look at my answer.

Comment: Isn't the question rather about to find $\alpha, \beta$ such that $A,B,C$ are collinear, i.e. $AB\parallel BC$?

Comment: Yes but a think getting the third vector help me find alpha and beta. If I'm not thinking right, you can point me to the right path

Comment: So is the question to find the parameters such that A, B and C lie on the same **line**?

Comment: Yes. But I'm thinking, since for them to lie on the same plane, a.( b x c) = 0. It means a = 0 or (b x c) = 0. Please is it so?

Comment: You seem to be confusing a plane with a line. And for a.(b x c)=0 it is not necessary that a=0 or (b x c)=0.

Comment: @HarisGusic Not on the same line. On the same plane. They lie on the same plane

Comment: Alright, then my answer is valid. If you don't know how to solve a (b x c) = 0, see scalar triple product on the following link. The easiest way is using determinants. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product

Comment: I have solved it. Thanks

Comment: Write your solution up as an answer, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any three points in 3D space will inevitably be on the same plane.

To show this, you can take:

$$\vec a = \overrightarrow{AB}$$
$$\vec b = \overrightarrow{BC}$$
$$\vec c = \overrightarrow{AC} = \overrightarrow{AB} + \overrightarrow{BC}$$

and you will get that $\vec a \cdot (\vec b \times \vec c) = 0$, regardless of $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Comment: This will go a long way. Let me get back to work. Thanks

Comment: @Atoms If I answered your question, you can mark it as accepted.